# What is the sort order returned by getIterator() method of aws dynamodb for php?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

So here's the thing,I am using Amazon aws dynamodb's php sdk and  need to apply pagination in one of my site pages that renders records from a table.I went through this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-iterators.html
and this:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/TxJGHHKBUJO1AL/Iterating-through-Amazon-DynamoDB-Results.

And decided to use getIterator() method for paginating the results.BUT, i need to know the order of the results returned by getIterator() method.I know that i can use a Global Secondry Index to sort the results ,but for that i have to use the 'query()' method. 
I may be missing something here.

Please someone suggest me how can i sort the results obtained by getIterator() method.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implied ordering when scanning a table. The order of the items returned to you is more or less the ordering induced by the hashing of the partition key (which used to be called hash key) internally by the DynamoDB service.

If you need strong order guarantees you need to implement that yourself by using a combination of index and range key however, I would argue that if you find yourself in a position to need strong order guarantees across all items in a DynamoDB table you may be using DynamoDB incorrectly.

The best option for paginating DynamoDB results is to try to map it to an *infinite* scrolling pattern where you simply use the last evaluated key to request the next batch of items. That way you don't have to worry about ordering and you can keep your code relatively efficient.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement your suggestion.